# Weapons selection by God Vishnu in his Dasavatara

Tags: vishnu, avatars, weapon

If we note carefully in the first five avatars Maha Vishnu will not have any weapon. Parasurama avatar has axe as weapon, Rama avatar has bow and arrow, Balarama avatar has plough, Krishna avatar nothing [although he used chakra to control bheeshma] and ain kalki avatar sword is the weapon mentioned int he pictures. Default weapons are shanka and chakra of Mahavishnu. Any scriputural or puranical reference how the weapon selection was made by God Vishnu during each of his avatar.

Comment: Balarama was sheshnaag not lord vishnu